# Scrolling an element into view with iOS native app

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile-automation, ios, mobile-applications

I am using Appium + Selenium + Java.

I am testing a native app and I sometimes need to scroll an element into view in order to click on it. It seems like, when testing a web app on iOS, you can use [this](https://developers.perfectomobile.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=25199704) to scroll. However, I am testing a native app and this doesn't seem to work.

I tested this solution with:

```java
RemoteWebElement parent = (RemoteWebElement)driver.findElement(By.className("XCUIElementTypeTable")); //identifying the parent Table
String parentID = parent.getId();
HashMap<String, String> scrollObject = new HashMap<String, String>();
scrollObject.put("element", parentID);

// Use the predicate that provides the value of the label attribute
        
scrollObject.put("predicateString", "label == '"+text+"'");
driver.executeScript("mobile:scroll", scrollObject);  // scroll to the target element
```

---

I found [this proposed solution](https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/430) however, the "IosUIAutomation" or "findElementByIosUIAutomation" that we are supposed to use in this solution doesn't exist with my version of Appium + selenium.

I still managed to test it with:

```java
String uiautoFind = "UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow()" +
                    ".scrollViews()[0].cells().firstWithPredicate(\"label = '"+text+"'\")";
((IOSDriver<MobileElement>)driver).findElementByIosNsPredicate("label = '"+text+"'");
((IOSDriver<MobileElement>)driver).executeScript(uiautoFind + ".scrollToVisible();");
```

But this solution didn't work either.

---

### Question

So, how can I scroll an element into view on an iOS native app?

Please note that, even though I am looking for the *exact* label on the example I gave, I would much prefer a solution where I would look for a "contain" and not an "equal".

---

As a side note, here is how I do it on Android (and it's working fine):

```java
(MobileElement) ((AndroidDriver)driver).findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable("
            + "new UiSelector().scrollable(true)).scrollIntoView("
            + "new UiSelector().textContains(\""+text+"\"));");
```

Answer (score 1):

When I have tackled this in the past I used a loop and [TouchActions](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/touch-actions/). Treat the following sample as pseudo-code.

```
var element = driver.findElement(mySelector);
while(!element.IsPresent) {
    TouchAction()
    .press(100,100) // Start at 100,100
    .moveTo(200,200); // Passing absolute values of 200,200 ending up at 200,200
    element = driver.findElement(mySelector);
}
```