# Appium How to iterate over a listview of unknown length?

Tags: automated-testing, c#, appium

```cs
IList<AppiumWebElement> els = AppiumDriver.FindElementsByClassName("android.widget.LinearLayout");
var loc1 = els[12].Location;
var target = els[1];
var loc2 = target.Location;
var touchAction = new TouchAction(AppiumDriver);
touchAction.Press(loc1.X, loc1.Y).Wait(800).MoveTo(loc2.X, loc2.Y).Release().Perform();
//Assert.AreNotEqual(loc2.Y, target.Location.Y);
```

In mobile automation testing, I can swipe and click to element in the list. But I have to loop this.

The list consists of 30 items. It is iterated after every 10 elements.

How can I do this?

Comment: I posted pseudo-code on a [similar question](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/45643/11015) but it's like @Moorpheus said, loop scrolls until you see the element.

Answer (score 1):

Are there any elements that come after the list? E.g. a footer?

You could potentially have your loop check whether those elements are displayed/visible. When you're at the bottom of the list and they're visible then the loop would break.